# Quantitative methods and statistics conferences in psychology?

Tags: conferences, psychometrics, psychology

What are the most significant annual conferences focusing on quantitative methods in psychology?

This could include but is not limited to psychometrics, mathematical psychology, and statistical methods in psychology.

Rules:

- One conference per answer
- Include a link to the conference

Answer (score 4):

The [European Association of Methodology](http://www.eam-online.org/) has a meeting turning around statistics and psychometrics for applied research in social, educational and psychological science every two years. The latest was held in [Postdam](http://www.iqb.hu-berlin.de/veranst/EAM-SMABS) two months ago.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably already aware of it, but the Society for Mathematical Psychology has an annual conference, MathPsych, which is attached to CogSci (generally happnens in the same city either before or after) and blends statistical methodology and Psychological modeling.

They do a pretty good job getting big names to come present, it's pretty cutting edge.

2010 conference site: http://www.mathpsych.org/conferences/2010/

Answer (score 3):

The annual meeting of the Society for Computers in Psychology often features content on quantitative methods:

http://sites.google.com/site/scipws/